# How do I inject an entire object into a Cypher Query using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I have the following node code...

```
router.post('/node/source', function(req, res, next){
    var query = [
        'MERGE (source:Source {name:{name}, loc:{location}})',
        'RETURN source'
    ].join('\n');
    db.cypher({
        query: query,
        params: req.body
    }, function(err){
        if(!err){
            res.json(req.body);
        }
        else{
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
    });
});
```

This works great as long as I send the location and name, but what if I want to send different properties depending? Like maybe I only want to send the location sometimes, so I just want to inject the entire req.body object. Is there a better way that something like this...

```
var query = [
    'MERGE (source:Source'+JSON.stringify(req.body)+')',
    'RETURN source'
].join('\n');
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't know the node.js notation in detail. Cypher allows you to amend properties based on a map, see https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/set.

```
MERGE (source:Source {name:{name}, loc:{location}})
SET source += {additionalProps}
RETURN source
```

Your parameters are:

```
name: 'myname',
location: 'mylocation',
additionalProps: {prop1:'val1',....}
```

If your body object is a map, you might be able to pass that in directly.

Comment: I will try this, will my node have a property called prop1 or will it be n.prop1. Also where did that n come from? Is that a typo for source?

Comment: Sorry n is a typo, should have been 'source'. Your params don't need a prefix.